# How to run VB script from Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vbscript

Is there a way to run a vb script from MatLab code ?

I have a vb script that calls several macros in different excel spreadsheets and it would make my life easier if I could call it automatically at the end of a MatLab routine.

thanks !

Comment: Would it be acceptable to call the vba macros inside excel directly from Matlab? a.k.a. cutting out the middle man?

Comment: yes, that would be beautiful. although I was poking around and encountered several solutions for that problem, but all were based on using complicated activex and COM servers tools. you'll find some [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100938-how-can-i-run-an-excel-macro-from-matlab)